# Can I use PPhys2D with android?

Tags: java, android, physics

Is it possible to use [PPhys2D](http://pphys2d.jmcouillard.com/) on android?

Any help would bre greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean PPhys2d as can be found [here](http://pphys2d.jmcouillard.com/).

In the download there appears to be Java source code and providing it doesn't require the use of Java Native Interface (JNI) there should be a good chance of it working on Android. Unfortunately it looks like you'll have to do all the legwork and compile it for android though.